# how do i show css/js spinner in angualrjs 2 using ts or HTML

Tags: angular

I cannot understand where to write the my css loader/spinner code exactly and I am also not able to use Jquery is ts language. So how can I show spinner in specific div elements of angularJS 2 page (which is loaded).

Example - Show spinner on page or on specific div element untill the http get data is not received ???

please give you expert opinions and referrences to link to help solve this problem.

Comment: For jquery integration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054004/how-to-use-jquery-with-javascript-in-angular-2

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this global spinner using `shareservice` concept. In short, I have made one service for spinner which can be used whenever you want and where ever you want. Have a look here answer is already given

[How to make a preloader with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455577/how-to-make-a-preloader-with-angular2) 
NOTE: This was made with angular beta version.

**service.ts**

```
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

export interface ILoader {
   isLoading:boolean=false;
}

@Injectable()
export class sharedService { 
  loader:ILoader={isLoading:false}; 
  showLoader()
  {
    console.log('showloader started');
    this.loader.isLoading=true;
  }
  hideLoader()
  {
    this.loader.isLoading=false;
  }
}
```

Whether you are using patent-child components, routing or no relation between component, this will be useful I guess.

Comment: If a parent component references two child components, how would you inject separate instances of this service in to each child while allowing the parent to set them to a 'Loading' state independently?

Comment: use `providers` array or `viewproviders`.

Comment: I haven't used angular 2 before so maybe I'm confused, but how would you reference the child-injected instance from the parent in order to call `showLoader()`?

Answer (score 1):

I created a few functions for Show & Hide Page level Loader and Show and Hide Loader Panel/div Container Level ... which manipulates the html directly ....

here's my code

```
loading = document.createElement('div');
img = document.createElement('img');
constructor() {

    this.img.src = 'app/template/img/loading.gif';
    this.loading.id = 'loading';
    this.loading.appendChild(this.img);
  }

 showPageLoader() {
    document.body.appendChild(this.loading);
  }
  hidePageLoader() {
    document.getElementById('loading').remove();
  }

  showLoader(panelID: string) {
    document.getElementById(panelID).innerHTML += '<div class="loader-text">\
                                                      <div class="text">Loading data\
                                                          <span>\
                                                              <div class="dot dot1"></div>\
                                                              <div class="dot dot2"></div>\
                                                              <div class="dot dot3"></div>\
                                                              <div class="dot dot4"></div>\
                                                          </span>\
                                                      </div>\
                                                  </div>';
    document.getElementById(panelID).className += ' loaded';
  }

  hideLoader(panelID: string) {
    document.getElementById(panelID).className = document.getElementById(panelID).className.replace(' loaded', '');
    $('#' + panelID + '> div.loader-text').html('');
    $('#' + panelID + '> div.loader-text').remove();    
  }
```

now I just need to use the service to show and hide the loader at page or specific div-panels... Thanx micronyks for the hint